# unable display template variables on webpage in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am unable to show data from the database to HTML. I am getting ordered dict from the serializer.

***views.py***

```
 material_class = Material.objects.filter(material_class=user_class.user_class)
 data = MaterialSerializer(material_class, many=True)
 content = {'material':data.data}
 # In *data.data* I am getting this [OrderedDict([('id', '123'),('material','456')]), 
 OrderedDict([('id','345'),('material','789')])]
 return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html',content)
```

***dashboard.html***

```
{% load static %}
{% csrf_token %} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% block content %} 
    {% for a in content %}
        <p>{{ a }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}  
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: always remember to keep track of key names in context dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in last line of your view.

```
return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', {'content': content})
```

You have to pass a dictionary of values and their keys. You were passing just the OrderedDict.

Comment: Thank you so much. you are the god.